# How to stop execution of a process after finishing it

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a code in eclipse where i have successfully established cassandra connection.The connection is successfully done, but i see the big red button in eclipse is sill on  i.e the process is not finished yet. i want to  off the the red button as execution of the normal code
does.  here is my code ...

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Host;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;

public class MyConnection{

private Cluster cluster;

public void connect(String node) {
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).build();
    Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
    System.out.println("Cassandra connection established");
    System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n",
            metadata.getClusterName());
    for (Host host : metadata.getAllHosts()) {
        System.out.printf("Datatacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s \n",
                host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack());

    }
}

public void close() {
    cluster.shutdown();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyConnection c = new MyConnection();
    c.connect("127.0.0.1");
    c.close();

}

}
```

This is the code .someone please help ..

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what eclips is doing but ran the same code [(slightly modified)](https://gist.github.com/lyubent/5788304) in intelliJ and the process completed on it's own, here is the output:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Cassandra connection established
Connected to cluster: Test Cluster
Datatacenter: datacenter1; Host: /127.0.0.1; Rack: rack1 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I then tried the following:

- Running the same code with the cassandra server switched off
- Running the same code on a remote server
- Running the same code on a remote server to which I dont have a connection (timeout)

All three cases resulted in errors but the code still exited on its own.

`cluster.shutdown();` is the correct to clean up the connection used by the `com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster` object. Using `System.exit(0)` will kill the process, but its considered bad practice. This code **should** execute and complete on its own. My advice is that you check your **Run** (execution) settings for anything that might be interacting / interfering with your application.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
System.exit(0);
```

this will off your  red button :-)

Comment: actually i think i should close the cassandra connection properly ..can any one help me??